# Validate data field in vue js

Tags: typescript, vue.js, validation

I have root and child componets.
I try add validation data on input event in child component and use result in root component.
In child

```
<ValidationProvider
      :bails="false"
      :rules="validation"
      slim
      :vid="id"
      ref="provider"
      :name="id"
    >
      <textarea
        :value="value"
        @input="onInput($event)"
        ref="area"
        :rows="rows"
      />
    </ValidationProvider>

extend('my', (value: string) => {
  console.log('extend ' + value);
  return !isNaN(+value);
    });
});

$refs!: {
    area: HTMLElement,
    provider: InstanceType<typeof ValidationProvider>;
  };

  async onInput($event: any) {
    const isTextareaValid = await this.$refs.provider.validate();
    console.log('valid ', isTextareaValid.valid)
    this.$emit('validation', isTextareaValid, this.$props.id); 
    this.$emit('input', $event.target.value, this.$props.id);    
  }
```

In root

```
<Child
          v-model="value"
          validation="required|my"
          @validation="check"
        />
<BaseButton
          type="submit"
          :disabled="!isValid"
          :text="text"
        />

private isValid: boolean = false;
check(result: ValidationResult, id: string) {
    this.isValid= result.valid;
  }
```

Now, how I understand, validate() work with previous value, when I start it onInput.
How I can send result of validation on changed input data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to go about this will be to emit whatever value is input into the child component and emit it to the root like this

#### CHILD COMPONENT

```js
onInput($event: any) {
  this.$emit('input', $event.target.value);   // you can only have two parameters here unless you use an object and de-structure it   
  
  const isTextareaValid = this.$refs.provider.validate() // the await isn't necessary here as `isTextareaValid` returns a boolean and not a promise
 
 this.$nextTick(() => { // this will wait for the next DOM update cycle to apply the validation check as Vue DOM updates are asynchronous
    if (isTextareaValid) {
     this.$emit('set-isValid-to-true');
    } else {
     this.$emit('set-isValid-to-false');
    } 
  }) 
}
```

#### ROOT COMPONENT

```js
<Child
  v-model="value"
  @set-isValid-to-true="setIsValidToTrue"
  @set-isValid-to-false="setIsValidToFalse"
/>
 
private value = '';
private isValid: boolean = false;

public setIsValidToTrue() {
  this.isValid = true;
}

public setIsValidToFalse() {
  this.isValid = false;
}

<BaseButton
  type="submit"
  :disabled="!isValid"
  :text="text"
/>
```

EDIT ---- alternatively, you can watch for changes

#### CHILD COMPONENT

```js
<ValidationProvider
 ...
>
  <textarea
    v-model="textValue"
    ref="area"
    :rows="rows"
  />
</ValidationProvider>

data() {
  return {
    textValue: ''
  }
}

watch: {
  textValue () {
    const isTextareaValid = this.$refs.provider.validate() // the await isn't necessary here as `isTextareaValid` returns a boolean and not a promise
    if (isTextareaValid) {
     this.$emit('set-isValid-to-true');
    } else {
     this.$emit('set-isValid-to-false');
    }  
  }
}
```

#### ROOT COMPONENT

```js
<Child
  @set-isValid-to-true="setIsValidToTrue"
  @set-isValid-to-false="setIsValidToFalse"
/>
 
private isValid: boolean = false;

public setIsValidToTrue() {
  this.isValid = true;
}

public setIsValidToFalse() {
  this.isValid = false;
}

<BaseButton
  type="submit"
  :disabled="!isValid"
  :text="text"
/>
```

Comment: I want use validate in clind component.

I think root component can't use this.$refs.provider.validate()

Comment: Hi, @klynxe. I have updated my answer. Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: @klynxe, that's how you get an emitted value from the child component. I emitted ('set-isValid-to-false') in the child component, and then in the parent component, using the child custom component, I get the emitted value. You can see more about this [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)

Comment: Tony, onInput in child component run this.$refs.provider.validate() with old value, not with $event.target.value. 
If I input
'a'
then add 'b' (result 'ab').
When I add 'b' validate check value 'a', but not 'ab'.
I think it is because I start this function on @input.

Comment: Could you console.log(the value of $event.target.value in the onInput method. Could you also edit your post with the implementation of `ValidationProvider` component?

Comment: If I use @blur validate work with correct data. But I want use validate after input event

Comment: Ok. Also, are you using Vuetify?

Comment: One thing that may be preventing the first solution from working is [nextTick](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2019/01/22/vue-what-is-next-tick/). I will update my first solution to include it.

Comment: Whan I input '1'
extend->
extend ->
valid false->
check false->
extend 1->
extend 1->
extend 1->
When I add '2'
extend 1->
valid true->
check true->
extend 12

Comment: I think the same about nextTick, but I din't know how fix it)

Comment: I have updated both solutions. See if they work for you.

Comment: I am happy to have helped. Just for the record and for the benefit of whoever comes across this post in the future, which one resolved your problem? @klynxe

Comment: I use first case, but I think the second case mast work the same